# How to remove indents from multi-line string given by $(...).html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, trim

`$(element).html();` returns html of given element and all it's indents.

**html**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <section>
      <ol>
<!-- embeded comment with no indents -->
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
         <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
         <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
$('section').html();
```

**will return**

```
      <ol>
<!-- embeded comment with no indents -->
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
         <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
         <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ol>
```

How can I remove indents (and indent comment if possible), to have following result:

```
<ol>
  <!-- embeded comment with no indents -->
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). Before embedding, try http://jsbeautifier.org which based on this library.

Comment: This is a helpful suggestion, but beautify may cause a code inside ol tag to be reformatted in a way which i would like to avoid, for example might break li > p into two lines instead of keeping one, or other scenarios. I have checked their code and they have `beautify-html.js` which might be useful anyway.

Comment: There are several options there. if specific scenarios are needed, you cannot avoid of some customization, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wil probably have to wirte my own script for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have written custom function for this

```
function trimmedHtml(element){
  var html = $(element).html();

  // find shortest html element indent
  var shortestIndent;
  html = html.split('\n');
  for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
    // for each line
    var line = html[i];
    // ignore comment lines in searching
    if( $.trim(line).substring(0, 4) != "<!--" ){
      // count number of spaces before code for current line
      var spaces = line.search(/\S/);
      if( (shortestIndent > spaces || shortestIndent == undefined) && spaces >= 0 ){
        shortestIndent = spaces;
      }
    }
  }

  // remove spaces before each line (align to shortest indent)
  for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++){
    // for each line
    var line = html[i];
    if( $.trim(line).substring(0, 4) != "<!--" ){
      // if line is not a comment, remove spaces
      html[i] = line.substring(shortestIndent, line.length);
    } else {
      // if line is a comment:
      // remove it's spaces
      html[i] = $.trim(line);
      // align to shortest line, and add 2 spaces
      for (space = 0; space < 2; space++) {
        html[i] = " " + html[i];
      }
    }
  }

  // join all lines
  html = html.join("\n");
  return html;
}
```

then use as:

```
console.log( trimmedHtml($('section')) );
```

Answer (score 0):

After see this response I understand that it wuold be better to write my own solution, so here it is :

```js
function trimHtml(html){
  var htmlArray = html.split('\n'),
    htmlToRetun = [];

  return _.map(htmlArray,function(line){
      //per ogni linea trimmo 
      return jQuery.trim(line);
    }).join('\n');
}
```

This function will return an undented html from a string.

I use lodash to _.map the array, but you can use javascript .map function.